# Can this be completed entirely in SQL Server to support a BULK INSERT? Fixed width text file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a file that has an odd format (screenshot attached).

The first row can be ignored completely since this is a summation of the columns below.

I am guessing an easy fix to ignore this would be `FIRSTROW = 2,` in a SQL Server statement.

The remaining issue is that there are variable amounts of spaces between the fields (and before the first column)

Since this is a Bulk Insert, how do I represent "FIELDTERMINATOR" to basically say "accept any amount of white space/space in each line as a filed terminator"
while still ignoring the initial spaces?

Thank you so kindly for any insight or recommend way to handle this.

[image: Data format in file]

Comment: You can specify the columns as fixed positions.  This is particularly important if any values are missing.

Comment: Just to comment that it's not an odd format, it's a fixed width file where you typically don't have any separators (different columns can be directly next to each other) and all columns have a fixed length. These used to be a lot more common in the old times ;)

Comment: You should be able to import this using a format file at least.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm awkwardly new so when you say using a format file can you give an example of one? Is that then able to be used with a Bulk insert?

Comment: Microsoft has many documentation pages on Bulk Insert and Format Files. [Use a format file to bulk import data (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server) is as good a place as any to start. Googling `"bulk insert" "format file" "fixed width"` would also provide many useful links.